# Microsoft Edge still not saving passwords

Tags: windows-10, passwords, microsoft-edge

My Microsoft Edge is not saving passwords, despite all efforts that I've tried.

As explained [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/microsoft-edge-is-not-remembering-login-data/07c631e6-58b2-4cb0-bdba-a2c492053608)

> I can see all over the internet this seems to be a common issue, but Microsoft don't seem to be acknowledging it.
> Any help greatly appreciated.

I've consulted the reports/solutions [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/microsoft-edge-not-saving-passwords/c8284790-4c03-4410-8ce3-c55e16c1bdf4), [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/microsoft-edge-is-not-remembering-login-data/07c631e6-58b2-4cb0-bdba-a2c492053608), [here](https://www.technipages.com/fix-microsoft-edge-does-not-remember-passwords) and [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/edge-still-not-saving-passwords/8dcf77d6-9dc4-45b6-9794-0191fbc5a2a7), but nothing works for me so far.

Let me stress that,

1. this is not a misconfiguration issue, as things has been working before, and *all of the sudden* Microsoft Edge is not saving passwords any more, and I'm asked for passwords even for sites that already have passwords saved.
2. this is not a messed up machine but a brand new machine instead. I.e., the Windows and Microsoft Edge are both brand new, only a few days old, and I don't mess up with any settings unless absolutely necessary.

[image]

Reposting from [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftedge/forum/all/microsoft-edge-is-not-remembering-login-data/07c631e6-58b2-4cb0-bdba-a2c492053608),

> There are three known causes of this behaviour:
>
> 1. A bug in Edge that caused some cookies to be deleted when they shouldn't have been. This was corrected with an update to Edge 86.
> 2. A change in the way Windows protects sensitive personal data like passwords. This change was introduced with Win10 v. 2004, but the bug it woke apparently only affects users who are signed in to Windows with a local account. A fix has already been deployed to Windows Insiders and will be rolled out in an upcoming Windows Update. See the troubleshooting steps and workaround here: Outlook and other apps won't remember password after Windows Updates
> 3. Interference from third-party security software. Several cases have been reported where uninstalling the software solved the problem; offending products include Norton and iolo.

I don't know how much the above points still holds, as almost a year has passed since. But I'm sure the 3rd point doesn't apply (see my point#2 above).

Any help appreciated, and meanwhile, I'll submit feedback using the browser's built-in applet as prescribed in the above answer, but am really not sure how helpful / how soon the turn-around that can be...

Comment: I read your entire post. I have Chromium Edge 96 on a few machines and it seems fine. Make a new, test Windows User Account, log into the new Account and see if a new User Account makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @John. My Windows login account is a domain account and every of my daily activities are tightly coupled/entangled with this account. The site that the Microsoft Edge refuse to supply/remember password is an intranet TFS sever, which requires me logging in with my Windows domain  login account in order to access it. The suggestion is great for a general situation,  but for my specific situation, there are several difficult hoops that I need to jump through in order to try it. I'll try in the weekend...

Comment: A domain admin can disable this functionality with a group policy are you sure that isn’t happening?

Comment: Hmm..., @Ramhound, are you saying that our domain admin might have disabled our ability to save our password to our intranet TFS sever? If so, I can ask around. But while doing my "homework" searching for answers myself previously, I know that Microsoft Edge can make use of the Credential Manager, and I've tried to put my password there as well. So can Microsoft Edge making use of the Credential Manager be disabled as well?